# Please enable network time synchronisation in system settings geth windows 8.1

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, windows

I'm learning Ethereum and following [this](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8) tutorial to setup private chain on local machine.
All works fine, however when I try to run the node(s) it displaying me an warring `Please enable network time synchronisation in system settings`

[image]

If I run commands `w32tm /resync` and  `net time /domain` then warring goes away for time being, and then again comes unexpectedly.

Is there any permanent solution for that?